# webdriver manager update throws unhandled error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor and webdriver, when trying to do an update on webdriver manager I get the error below.

```
>     webdriver-manager update events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> 
> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
>     at ClientRequest.onConnect (\\hermes\vhd_profiles\VDI_Home_VHD1\modisej\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:166:19)
>     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
>     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
>     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
>     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
>     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

when I check the list of current available drivers using webdriver-manager status, i get the below.

```
    $ webdriver-manager status
    I/status - selenium standalone is not present
    I/status - chromedriver is not present
    I/status - geckodriver is not present
    I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
    I/status - android-sdk is not present
    I/status - appium is not present
```

But see the following when finding webdriver-manager version:

```
webdriver-manager version
I/version - webdriver-manager 12.0.6
```

Node Version: 7.2.1 
 Protractor version: 5.1.2 
 Webdriver version: 12.0.6

Answer (score 4):

webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://proxy:88

This solved my issue.

Comment: I get this error with the above command, appreciate any help.

[16:55:30] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json 'http://proxy:88/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases' -H 'host:api.github.com'
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 198.105.254.104:88

Answer (score 2):

managed to solve this by running the command

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy="proxy address":8080/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy="http://username:pass@yourproxyserver:port/" --ignore_ssl
```

worked for me with this command.

Update

With Chrome version

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 77.0.3865.90 --proxy="http://username:pass@yourproxyserver:port/" --ignore_ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the command
webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://proxy:88

[16:55:30] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json 'http://proxy:88/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases' -H 'host:api.github.com'
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 198.105.254.104:88